# Syntax highlighting for two components of C syntax

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, filetype-c

What are the following two components that I need to target with syntax highlighting/rules?

[image]

1. The first one is the `int` (or more generall, any storage class) that I want to colorize. If currently have the following 'rule' in my `c.vim` file, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

   ```
   hi StorageClass ctermfg=21 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#0000ff guibg=NONE gui=bold
   ```
2. Why aren't the closing braces recognized (it works with `(...)` but not `{...}`)? How can I modify this rule to fix it?

Comment: Hey David, you need to add `int` to `StorageClass` using `syn keyword StorageClass int`.  That adds the word `int` to the keyword group `StorageClass`. You can then define the highlighting parameters for that group like you have done.  As for your second question, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Vee just tried that but doesn't seem to work in my case...any idea?

Comment: Is `syn keyword StorageClass int` located above the highlight statement in `c.vim`?

Comment: @Vee -- yea it seems like there are conflicts somewhere but I'm having a difficult time debugging it. Here is an example where `hello` works but `int` does not: https://gyazo.com/91331d5bbfd9c889b2dc3cb7c2a9174d (ignore the xBoolean keyword, I was just using that as an example).

Comment: @Vee actually, the whole thing was solved by putting it in `after/syntax` instead of `syntax`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Obviously, `int` is "Type", not "StorageClass".

Comment: @Matt I see, thanks. What's a `StorageClass` then in vim?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Storage_class_specifiers